# Apply chrome like tabs in Qt

Tags: qt, google-chrome, qt-creator, qt-designer

Ivan made this -- see http://ivan.fomentgroup.org/blog/2009/03/29/instant-chrome/ -- but I don't know how since I am new to Qt. Does anyone have Idea how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first trick is that the window does not have window manager decorations. This is a hint you need to give to the window manager using the NetWM stuff. The good thing is that Qt exports that functionality for you:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop

You see, they have the Qt::FramelessWindowHint, as explained here:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/qt.html#WindowType-enum

The rest is rather straight-forward. The tab-bar looks quite regular to me, it may be that you have to modify some widget properties (e.g. spacing).

Comment: Actually, it isn't that straightforward. All tabs run in different processes which communicate via D-Bus. The graphical output of each process is then X-Embedded into the main window.

Comment: To me it sounded like the question is about reproducing the appearance as depicted in the screenshot, not the functionality. And that one is already explained in the article.

Comment: True. It is indeed not completely clear what the OP is asking for.

Comment: In fact, I'm planing to make an editor, something like Kodapp and I want it to be minimalist. The idea of using chrome like tabs is that Will help to be minimal and useful. It's just like normal tabs but it doesn't have to have that much space. Qt::FramelessWindowHint would be interesting and I will try to achieve what I need.