# How to make tabs in Qt look like tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I don't want my tabs to have a Drag and Drop feature like Chrome (as covered by this question: [Apply chrome like tabs in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700829/apply-chrome-like-tabs-in-qt)) - I just want them to look like Chrome tabs.

I'm currently using `QTabWidget`, but its built-in shape `QTabWidget::Triangular` is so ugly. What do I need to use? Stylesheet or image or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `border-image` property of the `QTabBar::tab`. Just read the documentation as to how you could style `border-image`. There is a nice explanation in the documentation.

I have done something like this using above method.

[image]

You could do the same. To change the close button you could style `QTabBar::close-button`. 
The final answer is you can achieve what you required, just using Qt stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure how you can make it look exactly like Chrome, but you can try using  *border-top-left-radius, border-top-right-radius, border-bottom-right-radius, and border-bottom-left-radius* in Stylesheets

[Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html)

Comment: I tried this but the only thing it does is make the tab's corner round.